# How integrate google search into microsoft dynamics crm?

Tags: search, search-engine, dynamics-crm, crm

We are using Microsoft Dynamics CRM but a lack of Google like search engine is crippling our productivity. We have nearly 10 years of data but without a good search engine we end up rediscovering solutions.

I was wondering if it is possible to integrate custom Google search to our MS dynamics CRM? If it is possible, how do I go about solving this problem? Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know too much regarding a custom Google search, but Leon Tribe (a MVP) has posted a couple of blog posts recently on how to create what he calls a "universal search" facility in CRM - all done using the standard configuration tools within CRM (no custom code required).

It still uses the built in CRM search logic, but rather than searching only across an individual entity, his solution provides an ability to search across multiple entities (including custom ones) from a single search query.

Possibly not the ultimate answer to your problem, but might give you some ideas on something relatively simple to setup, with some degree of improvement, while you investigate more comprehensive options.

The links to his blog posts as follows:

http://leontribe.blogspot.com/2011/06/slightly-more-elegant-codeless.html

http://leontribe.blogspot.com/2011/06/codeless-universal-search-for-dynamics.html

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a Google/Web search fairly easily by using an HTML web resource.  Just go to the search engine you want to use, type in some search text and search for it.  From the search results copy the URL.  If I search Google for "bacon", this is the URL I get -

```
http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=bacon&pbx=1&oq=bacon&aq=f&aqi=g5&aql=undefined&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1252l1954l0l5l4l0l0l0l0l238l673l0.3.1l4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=707818aceea98c40&biw=950&bih=934
```

In the HTML web resource, you now just need to create a textbox and a search button and wire it up so that when you hit search it generates the URL above replacing "bacon" with whatever was typed in the search box.  You can use a javascript window.open(url); to get it to spawn the window with the search results.